# std::bad_alloc thrown after calling QIODevice::write() multiple times

Tags: c++, qt

So I have to go through a big file that I want to encrypt/decrypt.

I can't encrypt/decrypt the whole file directly so I do it chunk by chunk.

It works fine for the encryption but for some reason it crashes on the decryption part and throws an "std::bad_alloc" after trying to write the 255th chunk of data into the output device.

Here's the code :

```
bool CryptEngine::decryptByChunk(QtAES256& cryptEngine, QIODevice& source, QIODevice& dest, int chunkSize)
{
    while(source.bytesAvailable() > chunkSize)
    {
        QByteArray inputBuffer;
        QByteArray decryptedData;

        inputBuffer = source.read(chunkize);

        if (cryptEngine.decrypt(inputBuffer, decryptedData, CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::NO_PADDING))
        {
            dest.write(decryptedData);
        }
        else return false;
    }
    // ...
    // Some other operations...
    // ...
}
```

Here chunkSize is 1 MB.

The line throwing the exception is *dest.write(decryptedData);* on the 255th iteration.

Can someone please explain this behaviour ?

**Edit :**

Method used to fill decryptedData

```
bool QtAES256::decrypt(const QByteArray& cryptedArray, QByteArray& decryptedArray, CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::BlockPaddingScheme padding)
{
    decryptedArray.clear();
    //...
    decryptedArray.append(decryptedResult, arraySink->TotalPutLength());
    //...   
}
```

Where decryptedResult is a char*

Comment: bad_alloc could mean the heap is corrupt. Can you run your program using a tool like Valgrind?

Comment: @Waxrat I can't because the project is running on Windows and it would be too much work right now to make it run on Linux. I'll try to see if I can find an alternative to Valgrind for Windows.

Comment: Do you using `QByteArray::fromRawData` static method in `QtAES256::decrypt` method?

Comment: @ramzes2 No I'm not using the fromRawData static method

Comment: Can you please post part of `QtAES256::decrypt` method that related to filling data into `decryptedData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem using VMMap, a tool I downloaded after Waxrat suggestion.

I could see that the heap memory consumption exploded after calling `CryptEngine::decryptByChunk`.

And indeed I am writing into a `QBuffer` located on the heap (I thought it was a `QFile`).

So it seems that the system cannot find a big enough contiguous block to allocate and return `std::bad_alloc` when the buffer size exceed 256 MB.